# Game works fine in unity, Completely breaks in android (many sprites just not loading)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I recently made a 2d side scrolling game. In unity it runs perfectly with no errors. But when I play my published game in the google play store, Many of the assets just turn purple (The SFX still works though) [Here is the game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AB.FlyingBird). Please help

Comment: Try adding your shaders to the Always Included Shaders list. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GraphicsSettings.html

Comment: Check logcat for errors. It can help a lot. Looks like a problem with the shader, but you can find more detailed info in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has been solved [HERE](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1313516/texture-appears-pink-on-iphone-works-on-editor.html), hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you SOOO much. I genuinely don't think my game could've have been fixed without this!